# JavaScript bubble sort modification (Looping `i` stops before the sorting ends.)

Tags: javascript, sorting, bubble-sort

It's my first question. I study the bubble sort implementation in JS.

It seems that code not working correctly.
Help me please fix it

[pen link](https://codepen.io/dandgerson/pen/XgVRKb)

```
var arr = [11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13];
var n = arr.length;
var t;
var swap = true;

for (var i = 0; (i < n) && (swap === true); i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < (n - (i + 1)); j++) {
    if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
      t = arr[j + 1];
      arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = t;
      swap = true;
    } else {
      swap = false;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: It will work if you take out the `(swap === true)`.  What is this for?

Comment: What's the question here? You want to know how to stop the loop when sorting is done? Why sorting isn't working in some cases? Something else?

Comment: @DanielBernsons  i wanted to understand how my code should look to make my idea work In this example.
and that good man helped me in this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44877069/7360033

But in any case, I'm grateful that you tried to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var swap = true;
for (var i = 0; (i < n) && (swap === true); ++i) {
    swap = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < ( n - (i + 1) ); ++j) {
        if ( arr[j] > arr[j + 1] ) {
            temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            arr[j + 1] = temp;

            swap = true;
        }
    } 
}
```

Once loopi didn't swap any number, "swap" will be false, then we can exit the loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer); in particular, it would be great if you could give some explanation to your solution to give a better understanding of why your result works.

Comment: @YibinQiu Thank you, your answer was the most accurate, you helped me understand how my code should look to make my idea work In this example.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thanks for the advice, I'll definitely use your recommendations

Answer (score 1):

The loop doesn't know when the array is sorted, so you can't possibly know when to stop the `i` loop.

If you want the bubble sort to work, you should take out the `swap` variable logic.

```
var arr = [11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13];
var n = arr.length;
var t;
var swap = true;

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
            t = arr[j + 1];
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = t;
        }
    }
};
```

But a better way to accomplish bubble sort is [this](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/07/09/friday-algorithms-javascript-bubble-sort/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want early breaking of the outer loop, you can use labels in Javascript to accomplish this.

```
outer:
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    inner:
    for (var j = 0; j < (n - (i + 1)); j++) {

        if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
            t = arr[j + 1];
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = t;
        } else {
            break outer;
        }

    }
};
```

The [MDN Doc for label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) does indicate that these are very uncommon, but they are designed for exactly this purpose.

Please also note that I have not looked at the accuracy or otherwise of your bubble sort algorithm - if you are having problems with that then Junaid Ahmed's answer may assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

[Yibin Qiu had answered for my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44877069/7360033)

His answer was the most accurate, he helped me understand how my code should look to make my idea work In this example.

```
var arr = [11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13];

var n = arr.length, t, swap = true;

for (var i = 0; (i < n) && (swap === true); ++i) {

    swap = false;

    for (var j = 0; j < ( n - (i + 1) ); ++j) {

        if ( arr[j] > arr[j + 1] ) {
            t = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            arr[j + 1] = t;
            swap = true;
        }

    console.log('swap = ' + swap);
    } 
console.log('j = ' + j);
console.log('i = ' + i);
};
```